# PHP 7 version is not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, php7

I have recently updated by php. My php -v command show following result:

```
PHP 7.0.6-6+donate.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

But still phpinfo() function shows php 5.3.10 version

What should I do to start using it.

Comment: My system is Ubuntu 12.04, why would I look for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: As you are using PPAs, the PHP packages are (almost) the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SAPI for your webserver, f.e. either `libapache2-mod-php` for Apache2 or `php-fpm` for NGINX.  CLI version of PHP could be different from web SAPI.

For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS you need to also add `ppa:ondrej/apache2` if you intend to use Apache 2.x PHP module:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

If you had apache2 2.2.x installed previously, you need to remove it with:

```
apt-get purge 'apache2*'
```

This will remove all apache2 configuration files, so don't forget to backup your configuration (if you made any changes).

Comment: libapache2-mod-php : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.0 but it is not going to be installed

Comment: What happens when you do `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0` directly?

Comment: libapache2-mod-php7.0 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211 but it is not installable

Comment: Package apache2-api-20120211 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'apache2-api-20120211' has no installation candidate

Comment: Edited my answer. You are missing apache2 ppa

Comment: Still the same error after adding `ppa:ondrej/apache2`

Comment: And did you run `apt-get update` after adding additional PPA?

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.20-1+deb.sury.org~precise+4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Updated the answer again. It's better to install into clean system.